# Mock update method in Junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

How to write a unit test (via Junit) for the MongoTemplate updateFirst() method?

I have this service class:

```
@Service
public class TemplateServiceImpl implements TemplateService
{
    @Resource
    private TemplateRepository templateRepository;

    @Resource
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public TemplateDto create(TemplateDto templateDto)
    {
        TemplateDto result;
        templateDto.setDeleted(false);
        result = templateRepository.insert(templateDto);
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean update(ObjectId id, TemplateDto templateDto)
    {
        if (templateDto != null)
        {
            Update update = new Update();

            if (templateDto.getName() != null)
            {
                update.set("name", templateDto.getName());
            }
            if (templateDto.getTemplate() != null)
            {
                update.set("template", templateDto.getTemplate());
            }
            if (templateDto.isDeleted())
            {
                update.set("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
            }
            update.set("lastUpdate", new Date());
            return mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(id)), update, "template")
                    .wasAcknowledged();
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

I want to write a unit test for the update method. This is my relevant test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TemplateServiceImplTest
{

    @InjectMocks
    private static TemplateServiceImpl templateService;

    @Mock
    private static TemplateRepository templateRepository;
    @Mock
    private static MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    private static TemplateDto templateDto;
    private static List<TemplateDto> listOfTemplates;
    private static String requestBody;


    @BeforeAll
    private static void setUp(){
        templateDto = createTemplateDto();
        listOfTemplates = createListOfTemplate();
        requestBody = createRequesyBody();
    }


    @Test
    void create()
    {
        when(templateRepository.insert(templateDto)).thenReturn(templateDto);
        TemplateDto actualResult = templateService.create(TemplateServiceImplTest.templateDto);
        assertThat(actualResult).isNotNull();
        assertThat(actualResult).isInstanceOf(TemplateDto.class);
        assertThat(actualResult.getId()).isEqualTo(templateDto.getId());
    }


    @Test
    void update()
    {
        Update update = new Update();
/*
        when(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(templateDto.getId().toString())) ,update , TemplateDto.class)).thenReturn(
                UpdateResult.acknowledged());
*/

/*
        given(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(templateDto.getId().toString())) ,update , TemplateDto.class));
*/

        boolean actualResult = templateService.update(templateDto.getId(), templateDto);
        assertThat(actualResult).isNotNull();
        assertThat(actualResult).isTrue();
    }
// other methods...
}
```

When I run the test I get NPE for mongoTemplate at update method, I searched and I saw these 2 approaches:

```
            when(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(templateDto.getId().toString())) ,update , TemplateDto.class)).thenReturn(
            UpdateResult.acknowledged());
```

Or

```
    given(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(templateDto.getId().toString())) ,update , TemplateDto.class));
```

But none of them worked.

actually, how do I test the MongoTemplate update first method?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK `@Mock` doesn't work on `static` fields. And you haven't registered any behavior for the mocked `MongoTemplate`. So the method call will return `null` (the default behavior). On which you try to call a method -> `NullPointerException`. So either way will lead to a `NullPointerException` (no mock, or no behavior at all).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have successful several tests that i use static .the reason use static is because BeforeAll annotattion setUp method that is static , so I think static is not problem .

Comment: Include actual stacktrace I have no idea where NPE it comes from.

Comment: If that isn't the problem, than, as stated, the issue is the fact tha tyou aren't registering any behavior on the mock.

Comment: If you want to test just the `update` method, I dont think you are following a good approach. Better as `when(mongoTemplate.updateFirst(any(Query.class) ,any(Update.class) , anyString()).wasAcknowledged()).thenReturn(true);`

Comment: @Aman i used code you sent but now I have NPE at the this line in test class ,this code throw NPE !